# Is there precedent in the literature for a variant of a random geometric graph where vertices are the centroids of discs placed by random sequential adsorption (RSA)?

Tags: random-graphs, graph-theory

Imagine I form a random graph by simulating random sequential adsorption (RSA) of discs (each with the same radius $r$) on $[0,1]^2$ until I cover the plane at a density $\leq U$, where $U \leq (\approx 0.544$ to $0.550)$ (i.e. where $U$ is less than the jamming limit - [Cadilhe, A., Araujo, N.A.M., Privman, V. Random sequential adsorption: from continuum to lattice and pre-patterned substrates. J. Phys. Cond. Mat. 19, 065124 (2007).]).  I then treat the center of each disc as a vertex, and join vertices within some cutoff distance $D$.

Is there precent for this sort of "RSA-RGG" random graph in the literature?  Specifically I'm looking for calculations / approximations for the connectivity or percolation threshold for such graphs?

Comment: Interesting question, but there doesn't seem to be much; a quick search unearthed the recent arXiv:1604.01452.  In general, you can try methods from standard RGG models.